# How to group by sum of measurement variables without explicitly naming them?

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I want to write a function to analyze a data set where I need to aggregate/group by/split on each combination of identification variables. Unfortunately the measurement variable are numerous, often change and enumerating them leads to brittle code and bugs in the inputs.

```
dat <- data.frame(id.a=c('aa','bb','aa','bb'),id.b=c('x','y','x','x'),m.c=c(1:4),m.d=c(5:8)) 
id.vars <- c('id.a', 'id.b')
measure.vars <- setdiff(names(dat),id.vars)
```

I would like to sum up my measurment variables.  I have found ways but they are all hacky. The result would be

```
id.a id.b m.c m.d
1   aa    x   4  12
2   bb    y   2   6
3   bb    x   4   8
```

I think that reshape2 or ddply is likely to be a solution.

Comment: Perhaps a solution for the brittleness of the inputs would be to change your data structuring so you read in the name of the variable and its value into a dictionary. Then traversing that different ways you might be able to get what you want without having to try to deal with a whole outside package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With plyr:

```
ddply(dat, .(id.a,id.b), numcolwise(function(x) sum(x)))
```

Comment: This does however list out the measurement variables, which the question was trying to avoid.

Comment: I don't think I see that in his question. Other than... "The result would be..."

Comment: In the title of the post - ..."without explicitly naming them?"

Comment: Ah, thanks. It's updated accordingly. numcolwise() runs on all numeric columns - so there's no need to specify measure.vars.

Comment: Just what I have been looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Using your supplied code:

```
dat <- data.frame(id.a=c('aa','bb','aa','bb'),id.b=c('x','y','x','x'),m.c=c(1:4),m.d=c(5:8)) 
id.vars <- c('id.a', 'id.b')
measure.vars <- setdiff(names(dat),id.vars)
```

and then running:

```
aggregate(dat[measure.vars],dat[id.vars],sum)
```

produces:

```
  id.a id.b m.c m.d
1   aa    x   4  12
2   bb    x   4   8
3   bb    y   2   6
```

Comment: I don't think the as.list is needed on the grouping variables.

Comment: @TylerRinker - correct, the c() wasn't needed on the first set of variables either. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Though I am likely to use the ddply version due to its ease of permutation, thank you for showing me how to better use base.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` solution that will be memory efficient

```
dat <- data.frame(id.a=c('aa','bb','aa','bb'),id.b=c('x','y','x','x'),m.c=c(1:4),m.d=c(5:8)) 
id.vars <- c('id.a', 'id.b')
measure.vars <- setdiff(names(dat),id.vars)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = id.vars, .SDcols =measure.vars]
##   id.a id.b m.c m.d
## 1:   aa    x   4  12
## 2:   bb    y   2   6
## 3:   bb    x   4   8
```

Assuming that all the non-id columns are measurement columns (implied in the question, but not explicitly stated as a requirement), then the following would work

```
 DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = id.vars]
```